# How can I test if the hardware of my internal webcam is working?

Tags: linux-mint, hardware

My wife's notebook's (Dell, i7, 8g, Linux Mint 20 Ulyana) integated web cam isn't working. AFAI found the probable cause is a hardware problem in the camera. In this case it's useless to messing in system configurations if the camera is dead.

Is there anyway I can test if the hardware is actually working before I deepen in the SOs configurations ? Maybe some kind of command from grub or from recovery mode, or some live distribution for hardware test or something.

Comment: Is there a [pre-boot diagnostic check](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeHNSxW7VSM&ab_channel=DellSupport) for the webcam?

Comment: Didn't know such a thing existed. Very useful. But ePSA doesn't have a test for webcams unfortunately. :(